# underscoreJS- form a new array with items in array1 but not in array2

Tags: underscore.js

Suppose I have array1 and array2 , need to find a method by which i can find the items in array1 but not in array2,

```
array1":[{"name":"tom","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"tomjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:4"},{"name":"will","lastname":"rogers","emailId":"willrogers@gmail.com","$$key":"object:24"},{"name":"matt","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"mattjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:84"}]
array2":[{"name":"tom","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"tomjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:4"},{"name":"matt","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"mattjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:84"}]
**i need to get a new array** 
**result:**[{"name":"will","lastname":"rogers","emailId":"willrogers@gmail.com","$$key":"object:24"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**reject**](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) and [**some**](http://underscorejs.org/#some):

```
var result = _.reject(data.array1, item => _.some(data.array2, { $$key : item.$$key}));
```

or without arrow function:

```
var result = _.reject(data.array1, function(item) {
    return _.some(data.array2, { $$key : item.$$key}); 
});
```

```js
var data = {
 "array1":[
  {"name":"tom","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"tomjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:4"},
  {"name":"will","lastname":"rogers","emailId":"willrogers@gmail.com","$$key":"object:24"},
  {"name":"matt","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"mattjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:84"}],

 "array2":[
  {"name":"tom","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"tomjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:4"},
  {"name":"matt","lastname":"jacob","emailId":"mattjacob@gmail.com","$$key":"object:84"}]
}

var result = _.reject(data.array1, item => _.some(data.array2, { $$key : item.$$key}));

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore.js"></script>

<p>
  <pre id="result"></pre>
</p>
```

Comment: ,this is throwing me an error while using with angularJS.                       Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: weird though i m having that error while running this snippet too .. not able to figure out what's wrong

Comment: It may be that you are using a browser that doesn't support arrow functions. I've added a version with the full function definition.

Comment: Thank you @GruffBunny , the version with full function definition worked for me